# General solution to this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Was reading through my notes on Fourier transform but couldn't figure how to find the general solution to
$$\frac{\delta  U(\omega ,t)}{\delta t} = -k\omega ^{2} U(\omega ,t)$$.
I must definitely have done it before but couldn't remember the technique used for finding the general solution to this ODE.
Method of undetermined coefficient, perhaps?

If someone could give me a leg up I would be on my way.

TIA

Comment: Hint: Which functions equal their own derivative (up to a constant)? It's one of the simplest ODEs that you know from your calculus course.

Comment: It's an exponential function. I'm looking to recall the specific technique.

Comment: It's not much to recall then: $dy/dt=ky \iff y(t) = A e^{kt}$. That's all you need here.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was helpful.